# Replacing word in a file at specific line, using c

Tags: c

In a file I have a few lines like so:

`The procedure at A1 is complete
The procedure at B132 is incomplete
The procedure at C45 is incomplete
The procedure at D2 is complete`

If I know I want to change the procedure at line 3, to X4534

`The procedure at C45 is incomplete`
to
`The procedure at X4534 is incomplete`

What would be an easy way to do this?

I've looked at the `fseek` function, which I'm thinking I could loop until I hit the desired line, go ahead 18 spaces, and `fwrite` there but the "is incomplete" text is still needed

Comment: There is no real "replacing" function in C, you need to overwrite all following words.

Comment: You should read from original file, transform, write to a temporary file, then rename the temp file to original one. Overwrite also works, but the logic will be a little bit messy as you need to move content after the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of replacement (where the length of the string to replace and the string to replace it with are different lengths), you will generally want to read from one file, and write the altered data to a different file.

You can read the file in line-by-line, and then use [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html) to determine whether the line needs replacing.

For example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    FILE *output = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    char target[] = "C45";
    char replacement[] = "X4534";
    char lineBuffer[100];

    while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof lineBuffer, input) != NULL)
    {
        char procedure[10];

        if (sscanf(lineBuffer, "The procedure at %9s", procedure) == 1)
        {
            if (strcmp(procedure, target) == 0)
            {
                // if we get here, then the line matched the format we're
                // looking for and we can therefore write our replacement
                // line instead.
                fprintf(output, "The procedure at %s is incomplete\n", replacement);
                continue;
            }
        }

        // if we get to this point, then the line didn't match the format
        // or the procedure didn't match the one we're looking for, so we
        // just output the line as it is.
        fputs(lineBuffer, output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

The code above should give you some idea of what's involved. Once you have `out.txt` saved, you can move it over the top of `in.txt` using the standard C function [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html), e.g.:

```
rename("out.txt", "in.txt");
```

Comment: `sscanf(lineBuffer, "The procedure at %9s is incomplete", procedure)` has the impression that `"is incomplete"` is significant.  `sscanf(lineBuffer, "The procedure at %9s", procedure)` would work just as well.

Comment: `sscanf()` returns 1, once something is scanned into `procedure`, regardless if the rest of input matches `"is incomplete"` or not,